# how to run find command on shell to get a part of the pathfile into variable?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, find

I'm trying to get content of files spread on specific folder.

```
find /tmp -name '*.txt'
```

This give me:

```
/tmp/s3400/10.txt
/tmp/s3544/1212.txt
```

I need to store "s3400" value on a variable to run another command and save the log as "/store/logs/s3400.log"

Note: Each subfolder in /tmp/s* only have 1 txt file. Is a txt file that stores some logs. I need to parse that text with other script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the `-exec` / `-execdir` ops, they can do whatever you want with the paths, at one extreme they can generate commands  you can `source /dev/stdin <<EOD` the `find`'s output.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why don't you need `s3544`? Is it only the first one that you need?

Comment: I need all txt files saved on /tmp/s* ... then run another script like this: /parser.sh /tmp/s3400/10.txt -output /storage/logs/s3400.log
Basically, is to know the id (s3400,s3544) on the logs folders.

Comment: Based on your comment, perhaps adding a `-exec dirname {} \;` would do the job.

Comment: But if you want to collect **all** the pathes and process them later, I would suggest that you switch to bash, ksh or zsh, where you have arrays.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
find /tmp -type d -regex '/tmp/s[0-9]+' -execdir /path/of/your/parser.sh {}/*.txt -output /storage/logs/{}.log \;
```

[image: test screenshot]

1. first, find the directory named "s+Num"  -> **find /tmp -type d -regex '/tmp/s[0-9]+'**
2. Second, use the -execdir option to pass paths of the matched directories to the corresponding commands using the {} substitution symbol, respectively -> **-execdir /path/of/your/parser.sh {}/*.txt -output /storage/logs/{}.log ;**
3. The parser.sh script simulates modifying the content of the text (the sed command) and then copying it to the specified location (the cp command).

I hope this helps.